# Run iPhone Apps on MacOs Laptop for free

Tags: iphone, xcode-simulator

I have a .ipa file in my laptop and also have a Apple Laptop with MacOS. I do not have any iPhone. I want to run the app in my Laptop. [Doing a quick Google Search brought me this.](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/&ei=PuMLUYSjNsrirAfRmoGQBg&usg=AFQjCNEYhEzQHcXFZ_wlc2RkaAmBDO0mbw&sig2=lRxe63U6W5HJU9RsVy1lIQ&bvm=bv.41867550,d.bmk), which looks like costing $99 for each year. I just want to run the app for free, what should I do?

Comment: You can't. You can't even run them using the developer tools. The iOS simulator is just that. It doesn't provide a suitable platform for a true working environment.

Comment: By the way, a developer account isn't needed to use the iOS Simulator, or even develop an app. It is just needed for when you want to publish  an app or test it on an actual iOS device. XCode is free and comes with the iOS Simulator.

Comment: @cksum Can you give me a link to some free software which will help me run the app?

Comment: @bassplayer7 Can you give me a link to some free software which will help me run the app?

Comment: There is none. iOS devices use a different architecture than desktop computers.

Comment: This [Wikipedia article may be helpful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa_(file_extension))note what is says about where .ipa's can be installed. Unfortunately, to run them in the iOS simulator, you will need all the original project files. Like @cksum, you can't just run an .ipa file on a Mac.

Comment: I think I'll just answer this.

Comment: What's the app name? Maybe there is an OSX equivalent that is free?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot run iOS applications on anything other than iOS. And you need a device capable of running iOS (iPhone or iPad).

The reason being is that iOS applications are compiled to run on the ARM-based processor. OS X (and most desktop or notebook operating systems) run on the i386 or x64 architecture.

To run a different arch-type, you'd need an emulator. And all Xcode has is a simulator.